# How to lazy load HTML images of unknown dimensions without browser reflow

Tags: html, angularjs, image, lazy-loading

In my Angular app, I need to display an unknown number of images with different unknown dimensions.

I'm lazy loading the images using a dedicated directive (angular-lazy-img;ng-lazy-image) and I use a default src image before lazy loading the real one when the image enters the viewport.

When the image enters the viewport I usually have a very visible reflow as the real image's dimensions and aspect ratio are different than the default one.

I thought that maybe there's a way to get the real image dimensions without actually downloading it, but it seems there's no apparent way to do that...

Another visible symptom of the same problem is when i change to a different view and then go back to the first view, all the images that were previously loaded in the first view are now back to the default image, and my vertical position in the page becomes off.

I was thinking that maybe one (very awfull) solution would be to track the scroll position, accumulate loaded images offsets and perform scroll manipulations in order to hide the reflow, but couldn't find any info on that too.

Any suggestions / clarifications would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you can know the image dimensions without downloading it. I would suggest you load the images slightly before they enter the viewport

Comment: How about styling the `img` tags according to different screen sizes using media queries? just give them width/height according to the media query.

Comment: Kobi, that won't help if I'm scrolling up, you'd still have that glitch

Comment: Muli, I'm not sure I'm following you... I want to show the full image and preserve its aspect ratio.